# What is twice the answer to this question?

Tags: logical-deduction, riddle

What is twice the answer to this question ?

Just thought some people here would like this brain-teaser ;)

Comment: Zero. … Ø, maybe?

Comment: @minitech In the same category, ε, the empty string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that your question is self referential and requests twice its own answer, we need something that is twice itself. Zero works - two times zero is still zero, so if the answer to your question is zero then twice the answer to your question is also zero.

Comment: But why should it be Zero in the first place?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Is there any reason why it shouldn't be zero?

Comment: Not really... just as there isn't any reason it shouldn't be potato :p Would you happen to have a reason that it _should_ be Zero?

Comment: But I see now why it might work well. +1

Comment: @d'alar'cop what if you worded the question "what is twice itself?" - you would answer in a heartbeat, right? Zero is the only number that works.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, or find x where 2x = x :)

Comment: @KateGregory: That's not true. Zero is not the only number that works. Infinity (∞) will also fit the answer.

Comment: @AeJey - So will minus infinity, $-\infty$; or [$\aleph_7$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number), etc.

Comment: `2x=x`   -->    `2=x/x`     -->     `2=1`

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 and that's why division by zero is not allowed

Answer (score 11):

Another possible answer is "deer".

Twice deer would mean two deer. And since the plural of "deer" is "deer" than "deer" is a possible answer.

Answer (score 7):

Another non-trivial possibility:

$\infty$

Answer (score 6):

It is [NaN (not a number)](http://jsfiddle.net/66yhg6cm), isn't it?

Comment: LOL! You actually tried to multiply "answer to this question" by 2 using code.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing.

Because twice nothing is still nothing.

Comment: I like this answer slightly better than "Zero". It's more general and includes the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question can be rephrased as "What is "the answer to this question" written twice in a row?"

This would be "the answer to this question the answer to this question".

Comment: @FlorianF, nono. I suggest that you just need to double the set of symbols: "the answer to this question". So the procedure must exactly the same as if you are asked "What is bla-bla said twice in a row?".

Comment: I understand now.  Comment removed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is twice itself. 2 possibilities so far. 
1. If it's a number, it can be 0 as well as infinity. 
2. If it's a statement, "twice the answer of your question" should work.